# Time Complexity for Insertion Sort on Ref. Based Linked-List?

Tags: linked-list, time-complexity, big-o

Here is the actual question:

"what is the time complexity if the insertion sort is done on a reference-based linked list?"

I am thinking it would be O(1), right? Because you will check the nodes until you find the PREVIOUS, and what should be the node AFTER, set the pointers, and you're good. Therefore, not EVERY node would need to be checked so it can't be O(n).

Comment: `O(1)` says the time it takes to sort is independent of the number of things you are sorting; that sorting 10 things takes the same amount of time as 10 trillion things.  That doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: Which notation, then, would imply that you only need to sort to a given extent? It cannot be just O(n) since not all nodes need to be checked. At least to my very basic and weak understanding.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you also need to consider all the nodes.  Suppose there was (any) sorting algorithm that always gave correct answers, but never looked at one of the elements.  Since that element is a black box one would be free to write anything inside, including either the minimum or maximum values of the list.  Since the "black box" element can be put in only one spot, this hypothetical algorithm can't always place it correctly.  So, we have  a contradiction and the algorithm does not exist.  All sorting algorithms must consider all elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big O notation generally refers to the worst case complexity.

Inserting into an already sorted list (Which I think is how you are understanding the question based on your final paragraph) would have a complexity of O(n), since the worst case is inserting an element that goes at the end of the list, meaning there are n iterations.

Performing an insertion sort on an unsorted linked list would involve inserting n elements into a linked list, giving a complexity of O(n^2).

Comment: Insertion sort also needs to navigate backwards through its list.  What time complexity does that imply for (singly) linked lists?

Comment: My mistake, I read it as inserting into a sorted link list. Fixing my answer now.